# Validation convention in python backend applications

Tags: python, backend, fastapi, pydantic, tortoise-orm

Supposing that I'm currently using **tortoise-orm**, and **FastAPI** along with **pydantic**.
Should I only use **pydantic validation** of request body or should I also validate record that I'm about to save in my database using validators provided by **tortoise-orm**?

I am currently doing double validation (**pydantic** and **tortoise-orm**) but I am wondering if it is needed or if it is just a redundant overkill.

Comment: Are you validating the exact same thing in both places? If so I would say it's overkill.

Comment: @paul41 yes for example i'm validating email in both places

Comment: Validation in Pydantic should be all you need then. With the validations being the same any issue would already be caught by the time it makes it to the tortoise-orm check.

Comment: Do you use the tortoise orm mapping outside of a web context? For example in cron, import jobs, etc.?

Comment: @MatsLindh No, just for Web context

Comment: There is no need to duplicate validation.